# CKEditor checkDirty() on source editing area

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, event-listener

Whenever one or more of my CKEditor WYSIWYG instances is changed, I give the corresponding textarea the attribute `data-dirty="1"`, so my application knows it has changed.

I'm using the following snippet for this:

```
$('textarea.wysiwyg').ckeditor(ckeditor_config, function () {
    var call_once = false;
    this.on('change', function () {
        if (this.checkDirty()) {
            if (!call_once) {
                $(this.element).attr('data-dirty', 1);
                $('#edit_form').change();
            }
            call_once = true;
        }
    });
});
```

This works nicely, unless the user only edits the HTML via the [Source Button](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcearea). In such cases, `checkDirty()` does not seem to get fired.

Does anyone know how I can get this functionality working on both views of the editor? I am using the latest version of CKEditor (CKEditor 4.5.7), full edition, so the plugins are the latest versions aswel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation for the `change` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) states:

> Please note that the `change` event is only fired in the [wysiwyg mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-mode). In order to implement similar functionality in the source mode, you can listen for example to the [`key`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key) event or the native `input` event (not supported by Internet Explorer 8).

```
editor.on( 'mode', function() {
    if ( this.mode == 'source' ) {
        var editable = editor.editable();
        editable.attachListener( editable, 'input', function() {
            // Handle changes made in the source mode.
        } );
    }
} );
```

If you are using jQuery adapter and multiple editor instances in one page, you can try below:

```
        $( '#editor1' ).ckeditor( function(){ this.on( 'mode', 
            function( evt ) {
                if ( this.mode == 'source' ) {
                    var editable = this.editable();
                    // Get the textarea
                    var element = $(this.element); 
                    editable.attachListener( editable, 'input', function( ev ) {
                        // Handle changes made in the source mode.
                        console.log( ev );
                        // Set an attribute on the textarea for handling
                        element.attr('data-dirty',1);

                    } );
                }
            }); 
        });
```

The above is the [callback function](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery-section-creating-editor-instances) will be executed on a single editor instance but if you specify selector covering multiple editor instances e.g. `.myeditor` then listener will be attached to every editor instance created by this method.

Comment: I will investigate this solution and let you know. Thank you, Anna!

Comment: Hi Anna, I've been experimenting with this, but cannot get it to work using the jQuery adapter. Also, please note there are several ckeditor instances in my page. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi j.swiderski. Thanks for this. I can register changes in the source now, the only snag still is to add the attribute `data-dirty=1` to the source textarea. Could you lean in?

Comment: I found it. The element is stored in `this`.